# How to select text that have a specific style applied by any CSS class? If it can be through XPath, better

Tags: javascript, css, xpath

```css
.s11 {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.s12 {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p class="s11" style="padding-top: 2pt;padding-left: 19pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: justify;">
    Further appeals.
    <span class="s7">Further appeals shall be in accordance with this section.</span>
</p>
<p class="s12" style="padding-top: 2pt;padding-left: 19pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: justify;">
    Suspending activities.
    <span class="s8">The activities suspended or revoked shall be informed.</span>
</p>
```

What I want to achieve is to get the text affected by the style `font-weight: bold;` regardless of the class that applies it, e.g.:

- Further appeals.
- Suspending activities.

Comment: I'm quite sure that there is no way to do this with XPath. Applied CSS doesn't affect inner/outer HTML of element (except adding pseudo-elements that also cannot be detected with XPath). XPath can only examine the HTML, but not how text is rendered on web-page. I guess you can do it with JS-execution if it's OK for your case

Comment: Please feel free to make any suggestion even if it is not using XPath for achieving the same goal. I'm using python + scrapy. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if something similar can be implemented in Scrapy. In Selenium you can do

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('<URL>')

paragraphs = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('p')
bold_paragraphs = [p for p in paragraphs if driver.execute_script('return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], null).getPropertyValue("font-weight")', p) == 'bold']
```

The point is to use JavaScript `return window.getComputedStyle(<WEB_ELEMENT>, null).getPropertyValue("font-weight")` that returns `"font-weight"` style value of specific element and you can filter list of elements by checking whether this value is equal to `'bold'` or not

Comment: I tried your code but **bold_paragraphs** is not being populated at all.
Testing the following scrpit in the browser console
```return window.getComputedStyle(<WEB_ELEMENT>, null).getPropertyValue("font-weight")```
throw: 
```Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement``` message

Comment: @yanes `<WEB_ELEMENT>` means you should pass WebElement here. Can you share page URL?

Comment: Of course I passed a web element, e.g.: 
```elements = document.getElementsByTagName('span');```
_> HTMLCollection(194)_
```return window.getComputedStyle(span[0], null).getPropertyValue("font-weight");```
_> Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement_
Sadly I cannot share any URL due to the HTML resides in a local file obtained after convert a PDF file into HTML file.

Comment: @yanes your code works fine for me if replace `span[0]` with `elements[0]`

Comment: @yanes Of course in Browser Console you should NOT add `return` but when executing JS in Selenium you SHOULD add that `return`: `driver.execute_script("""elements = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
return window.getComputedStyle(elements[0], null).getPropertyValue("font-weight");""")`

Comment: Anyway I realize that without the ```return``` it works perfectly on the browser console, e.g.: ```window.getComputedStyle(span[0], null).getPropertyValue("font-weight");``` On the other hand I also realize that the comparison needs to be done using **700** instead of the common weight name **Bold**, e.g.: ```window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], null).getPropertyValue("font-weight")', e) == '700'```.

Comment: @yanes it depends on app. [`font-weight` might be 100 ... 900 or "bold", "normal"...](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp)